# Delete duplicate records maintaining the most recent one

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, sparklyr

I am trying to delete duplicate records, seems that my code worked some days ago but has started failing.

This is some of the things I have tried

```
sdf_sql(spark,'DELETE pred FROM TB1 pred 
INNER JOIN TB2 pred2
WHERE pred.last_upd < pred2.last_upd AND pred.id = pred2.id')
```

This is the message error I get:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input 'pred' expecting 'FROM'(line 1, pos 7)

== SQL ==
DELETE pred FROM TB1 pred 
-------^^^
INNER JOIN TB2 pred2
WHERE pred.last_upd < pred2.last_upd AND pred.id = pred2.id
```

Comment: Hive has never supported `JOIN` or `FROM` in `DELETE`, so I doubt this ever worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code :

```
DELETE pred FROM contacts pred
        INNER JOIN
    contacts t2 
WHERE
    pred.id > t2.id AND pred.email = t2.email;
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/

Comment: That it is the exact code I am using, but seems not to work

Comment: You DELETE FROM - ditch the pred token.